# How to set this tableLayout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I want to Implement this type of View in My Application. . .

```
data1    hello   hi 
data2    hello2  hi
data3    hi      Hello
```

I want to know, which one is the best way to set it ??
TableLayout oranyother linearLayout.RelativeLayout  ???
I also want the xml code to set this layout. . 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow android:weightSum="3">
            <TextView android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="hello" />
            <TextView android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="hello" />
            <TextView android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="hello" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:weightSum="3">
            <TextView android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="hello" />
            <TextView android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="hello" />
            <TextView android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="hello" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:weightSum="3">
            <TextView android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="hello" />
            <TextView android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="hello" />
            <TextView android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="hello" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ok Nice. It works. Now if i want to give the More size to the Second Column then should i have to give the weightSum to 4 and the second textview to weight 2 right ???

Comment: I have set your layout but there is some problem.

Comment: If the first TextView of the table row getting long then it will seen bad with the another textview. What should i have to do to fit it to see it completely ?

Comment: you can manage by all the other textview by the way you want them.

Comment: JUST copy-paste this and see in yout layout window:

Comment: If you have any query you can come to casual chat room.. Thanks

Comment: <TableRow android:weightSum="4" android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/incomeTextRateText"
           android:text="Income up to $14000 taxed at 10.5%" android:layout_weight="2"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/incomeText" android:gravity="center"
           android:text="Income" android:layout_weight="1" android:singleLine="true"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/taxText" android:gravity="center"
           android:text="Tax" android:layout_weight="1" android:singleLine="true"/>
     </TableRow>

Answer (score 2):

`TableLayout` is preferrable in your case.
Example: https://web.archive.org/web/20210127143452/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2008/12/simple-tablelayout-in-android.html

Comment: Dear i have search on google for it. But I want such layout that fit with the width of the screen. And the Layout should be good in appearence. Thats why i have put question. Still i m not getting proper the answer. As i want the Layout that fit with the device screen.

Comment: set `fill_parent` to fill layout to whole screen